# npm install npm -g won't update npm to the latest version

Tags: npm

I am using npm v5.3.0.
Now I want to update npm to v5.4.1. To do this I type the following in my terminal:

`npm install -g npm`

without any errors. However, when I type `npm -v`, the version I get is 5.3.0, not 5.4.1.

I have to mention that I have changed the npm prefix to another directory.
How can I fix this?

I use [Ubuntu 17.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_17.04_.28Zesty_Zapus.29) (Zesty Zapus).

That's my console output:

[image]

Comment: I'm using 18.04 LTS, can't update either. However, I'm stuck at 3.5.2 instead.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46164420/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that I had set the PATH variable in my *`$HOME/.profile`* file wrong.
To help you understand, I had changed the npm prefix to *~/.npm-global*.

However, I set the path to *~/npm-global*. So I fixed the PATH variable in my *$HOME/.profile* file to point to *~/.npm-global* instead.

Answer (score 20):

I solved it on [Ubuntu 18.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_.28Bionic_Beaver.29) LTS (Bionic Beaver) by switching to *root* using `sudo su` and then I run the following:

```
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS too, really nothing has worked except this !

Comment: I noticed that `npm i -g npm` updates npm installed in `~/.npm` directory. This script works because it updates npm installed in `/usr/local/` directory. You can check yourself what path npm command is using by looking at `which npm` output.

Answer (score 5):

Please try this for the latest (5.4.1) version:

```
npm install -g npm@latest
```

or for any specific version, for e.g.:

```
npm install -g npm@5.4.1
```

**If that doesn't help**, go to where you have npm installed and **remove the files**: npm, npm.cmd.

After that please try to `npm install -g npm@5.4.1` again.

Comment: What does `npm outdated` command return for the npm package? What version have you set for npm in the dependencies?

Answer (score 3):

I had to dig a little bit more (probably I have some misconfig) and take an hardcore approach...
First I ran `which npm` to get the script that was running, that was `/usr/local/opt/node@8/bin/npm.js`.
From that script I saw that the npm package was actually in `/usr/local/opt/node@8/lib/node_modules/npm`.

So I ran

```
cd /usr/local/opt/node@8/lib/
npm i npm@6.11.2 # or your desired version
rm package-lock.json # clean up
```

And that did the trick.

NB: I'm not saying that you should do this right away. The first is better if you try the other approaches, but if other approaches are not working, give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

In my case ([Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29)), the only thing that worked was *reboot*.

After

```
npm install npm@latest -g
```

The output of

```
npm --version
```

was not changed (showing old version).

Unless I did a *reboot*.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade, run: `sudo npm install npm@latest -g`

The npm module is available for download at https://registry.npmjs.org/npm/-/npm-{VERSION}.tgz.

Comment: What does the console return ?

Comment: just a minute to see

Comment: I tried this, and now I am getting permission errors anytime I run `npm install npm@latest -g`.

Comment: isn't this a bad practice for `npm` to use `sudo`?

Comment: you have to use `sudo` to let `npm` write in root files

Comment: This question ist literally "what you propose didn't work" and you're like "hey do it again!"

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same error today. I updated [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js). Since npm comes bundled with node, npm was also updated, but the **updated npm version was not reflecting**. I, also, tried to update the npm version by using commands `npm install -g npm@latest`. But, the version was not reflecting.

This is how I resolved it.

1. A lot of post suggested to use the command `npm cache clean --f`. But, it did not work for me. Hence, I deleted the "npm" and "npm-cache" folders from the location *C:\Users\SearchYourUserName\AppData\Roaming*
2. Uninstalled again the existing node.
3. Reinstalled Node.js version v10.x.x. I downloaded the *node-v10.22.1-x64.msi* file from https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v10.x/ and installed it.

Then checked the npm version. It had worked.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by navigating in an admin command prompt to C:/Users//AppData/Roaming and then with rd /s /q (delete) the npm and npm cache folders. After that I am now able to update to the latest npm version of 9.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).