# Is `prefix ~/.npm-packages` the same as `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, sudo

I am not able to run `npm install npm@latest -g` without running into permissions errors and being forced to use `sudo npm install npm@latest -g`. I had been able to run this without using `sudo`, however, [I followed an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46165344/5590856) on StackOverflow that suggested using `sudo` and this seemed to mess things up. (I was never able to upgrade npm.)

Trying to rectify this sudo issue, I found a potential solution follow here, "Install npm packages globally without sudo on macOS and Linux"
https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md

Step 2 says: "2. Indicate to npm where to store globally installed packages. In your `~/.npmrc` file add: `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`"

When I open the `~/.npmrc` file, I see `prefix=~/.npm-packages`. Is `prefix ~/.npm-packages` the same as `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`, or do I need to add `${HOME}`?

I am running Mac 10.11.6. My npm is at v 5.6.0.

Answer (score 0):

In many shells "~" is an alias for ${HOME}. Using ${HOME} gets the shell to insert the Home environment variable and is more universal then "~".

Comment: Ok, I don't know why your answer was down-voted. To clarify, what you are saying is that these statements are the same, but `${HOME}` is less ambiguous than `~`?

Comment: Yes, in your case when the "~" is at the beginning of the string it is the same as ${HOME}. If the "~" is not the first character followed by "/" it can have other meaning.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!